PineScript not executing strategy.* for futures even when conditions are met
I have been pulling my hair out on this one and support was no help.
I have a strategy that executes for BCT and Stocks, but does not execute for ES or MNQ futures, even though the conditions are met.  Here is the conditional code I am using:
if canOpenShort and close > btm and close < top and strategy.opentrades == 0 and orderAllowShort 
    canOpenShort := false
    if tradeTarget and isLondonShort
        takeProfitShortPD := finalLondonLow
    log.info("ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ")
    log.info("TP from PDA: " + str.tostring(tpPDA))
    log.info("Take Profit Short: " + str.tostring(takeProfitShortPD))
    log.info("Stop Loss Short: " + str.tostring(stopPriceShort))
    log.info("Close: " + str.tostring(close))
    log.info("Updated Reward: " + str.tostring(close - takeProfitShortPD))
    log.info("Updated Risk: " + str.tostring((stopPriceShort - close)*2))
    updatedReward = close - takeProfitShortPD
    upatedRisk = (stopPriceShort - close)*2
    if updatedReward >= upatedRisk //(close - takeProfitShortPD) >= ((stopPriceShort - close)*2)
        //strategy.entry("Enter Short",strategy.short, qty=1)
        strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
        log.info("Short Position opened.")

        if tpPDA and orderplaced
            if tradeTarget and isLondonShort
                stopPriceShort := stopPriceShort 
            if takeprofits.get(currentSwingHigh) > 0.0 
                stopPriceShort := takeprofits.get(currentSwingHigh)
            else
                stopPriceShort := close + orderStopLossTicks/4

        strategy.exit("Short Exit PDA",from_entry="Enter Short",limit = takeProfitShortPD, stop = stopPriceShort, comment_profit = 'Long Profit Met (PDA)', comment_loss = 'Short Stop triggered')
        log.info("Short Exit Order opened with Take Profit at " + str.tostring(takeProfitShortPD) + " and Stop Loss at " + str.tostring(stopPriceLong) + ".")

        takeProfitShortPD := 0.0

The output log provides the following:
enter image description here
So you can see that the code is executing, but the strategy is not opened or closed.  I have adjusted the strategy properties to try every permutation of account size, order size, and contracts.  The code places orders for crypto and stocks, but even with all conditionals met and an account value of $1 million, no strategy.* methods are called and the strategy performs ZERO trades for futures.
Any ideas?
I tried running the code for BTC, APPLE, and TESLA which all worked as expected.  I ran the code for ES and MNQ and did not get any trades, even when all conditionals are met (see output log).  What am I missing?????????

Let's start with the fact that strategy can't work since there is an error with the from_entry=Enter Short parameter, which directs to the unexisted entry ID:
strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short)
strategy.exit("Short Exit PDA",from_entry="Enter Short", ... )

After fixing this issue, make sure that the amount of contracts (qty) that is generated by the strategy call is applicable for the initial capital and current symbol:
The strategy's Properties are incorrect
Every strategy has several parameters that govern its rules for opening orders. Authors can set these parameters from a strategy's source code, and users can override them with the inputs in the "Properties" tab of the strategy's settings.

NOTE: There are several places in a strategy's source code where users can set the number of contracts/shares/lots/units for its orders:

Parameters in the `strategy()` function allow users to set the default trade quantity and type, which sets the default values in the "Properties" tab. Users can override these values by adjusting the "Order size" inputs.
Order placement commands that produce entry orders, such as `strategy.entry()`, can set the trade quantity on an order-by-order basis. In this case, changes to the input in the "Properties" tab will not affect the strategy's order size. 
Users must ensure they specify the sizes of their strategies' orders correctly. To add to the "The strategy does not have enough capital to open a position" section above, you should note that:

If a strategy's "Order type" is set to "Contracts" (equivalent to `strategy.fixed` as the default_qty_type in the source code), the order size must be greater than 1 for most symbols. Some cryptocurrencies facilitate fractional sizes. For example, an order size of 0.1 is valid for BTCUSD but not for AAPL or EURUSD.
The order size must be positive; negative numbers will cause runtime errors, and a value of 0 will have no effect.
The total position size (number of contracts) cannot exceed 1e12. Strategies will not simulate new orders if the position size exceeds this number.



Thank you very much for your response, and thank you for catching the issue with the exit.  However, the code still doesn't open a trade.  I have changed the default properties in the code as well as in the properties window to try to get trades to execute for futures.  The code works for crypto and stocks, but not futures.
Here is the code for the strategy defaults:
strategy("My", overlay=true, margin_long=100, margin_short=100,
max_bars_back = 5000, initial_capital=1000000, currency=currency.USD, default_qty_value=2,
default_qty_type=strategy.fixed)
Thoughts?

Also, I am getting the same results from another, simpler script.  The code executes and log the comments/draws arrows for entries, but never executes orders for Futures bbut DOES execute for crypto and stocks.  I have set the account value to $1,000,000 and used both percent of equity (2%) and fixed quantity (2 contracts) and still no entries.

@TurboPascalRox It should work regarding to the info that you provided. something else in there. You need to provide full or minimal code to reproduce problem, symbol, and resolution. Or open support ticket with the full code attached and write me your TV userid after
